# Rename Apache Solr Collection or something like that

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, solrcloud, solr4

I know we cannot directly rename any solr collection. We can just create an alias that points to the collection. But we have the requirement to rename the collection. Is there any way to achieve the following in solrcloud?  (version: apache-solr version 8.4.1)

1. We have a main_collection (Which is we are currently using)
2. We have second collection temp_collection (Which we are planning to move)
3. we cannot migrate both
4. We have so many applications that are hardcoded to use main_collection
5. We have huge number of indexes in temp_collection.

Our idea initially was to rename the main_collection to backup_collection and then rename temp_collection to main_collection.

Is there any way to achieve the same. So that we cannot experience any downtime with the applications.

Comment: Be aware that `RENAME`-ing a collection in Solr is effectively not changing the name of the collection (i.e. the original name is still present in shard names, etc.). It is - in fact - just doing what you already mentioned, changing the alias of the collection. "Renaming a collection sets up a standard alias that points to the underlying collection, so that the same (unmodified) collection can now be referred to in query, index and admin operations using the new name.". Using aliases is the correct way to handle this without significant downtime.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh, can we create alias with the name same as collection? in our case: main_collection?

Comment: I'd try to avoid that, but renaming `main_collection` and creating the alias should be a rather quick process so the amount of downtime should be limited (maybe a few seconds? test it first). The problem is that you have the hardcoded references to `main_collection`, otherwise you could create `aliased_collection_name`, update configs to point to that, then swap that around as necessary later.

Answer (score 1):

You can try these steps.

1. Index your data in new collection.
2. Once all the data is indexed,create an alias to new collection. Give the alias name same as the old collection.
3. All your new request will be redirected to new
   collection.
4. Once everything is set you can delete the old
   collection.

Here you can find all the collection apis listed.
[Collection APIs](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/collections-api.html)